# When Im using soft keyboard in android, pointer events fires wrong stage coordinates

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air, coordinates, android-softkeyboard

when focus sets on textfield (or stageText activate) and softkeyboard opening, all touch(mouse) events fires worng localY,stage.mouseY coordinates.

On some android versions its a difference between softkeyboard height and stage height... But! when I start typing something in softkeyboard, coordinates changes again in non understandible way.

Is there any solution to get proper stage.mouseY coordinate when softkeyboard opened?

P.s.
I already done some schizophrenic solution for coordinate calculation, but it has a lot of minuses...

Comment: Touch events fire wrong coordinates on what object? What listens to touch events?

Comment: Are you listening for `softKeyboardActivate` or `softKeyboardActivating`? In your app.xml, what is your softKeyboard behavior set too? Is you `Application` class set to moveForSoftKeyboard or resizeForSoftKeyboard?

Comment: Can u show what r u doing ?

Comment: I have not set any begaviors in application. Of course Im listening softKeybActivate and etc... When soft keyboard shows, in my app nothing happens, I need to move/resize main container by myself...

The code is simple: 
stageText.activate(); or textField become in focus
stage.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TAP,function(e:TouchEvent):void{trace(e.localY,stage.mouseY});

When keyboard shows - localY and mouseY - incorrect. None of the tap events on displayobjects are working

Comment: Hum it might be silly but if you're interested in the active Textfield location you can (that's what I'm doing right now) listen to SoftKeyBoardActivate Event, then look for stage.focus which gives you the active TextField.